# How does deezer offline mode works

Tags: html, web-storage

I know there's a new html5 API called web storage, but it basically allows only up to 5MB of storage per domain, so how services like Deezer do to offer an offline mode ? It means that they have to store the musics on the computer, but it's all in the browser, so how do they do to bypass the 5MB of storage ?

http://www.deezer.com/en/features/everywhere.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Deezer, but there are several new APIs in development for HTML5 including the [FileSystem and FileWriter API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/).

In use cases it gives examples of large storage requirements the API will be able to fulfil such as storage of large media files and assets.

> Offline video viewer
>
> - It downloads large files (>1GB) for later viewing.
> - It needs efficient seek + streaming.
> - It must be able to hand a URL to the video tag.
> - It should enable access to partly-downloaded files e.g. to let you watch the first episode of the DVD even if your download didn't complete before you got on the plane.
> - It should be able to pull a single episode out of the middle of a download and give just that to the video tag.

It's still a working draft and [not very widely adopted](http://caniuse.com/filesystem).

Comment: Once supported, it will be very handy, but there's no way to use it in prod so far as there's only Chrome that supports it… Nevertheless, Deezer found a way to do the same kind of think, and that works on any browser (at least the ones that deserve that name)